# c code behaving weird. it gives segmentation fault when its only about to finish and return 0 from main function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I wrote some c code and compiled it with clang everything works fine until end when its time to return it gives segmentation fault which is weird because

last line of code are like :

```
  printf("End of program\n");
  return 0;
}
```

it even prints End of program and then gives me segmentation fault.
also when I tried to compile it on gcc it gives me segmentation fault quite early without doing much ( almost at the beginning) at all.

is there any way to find cause of these kinds of errors in c? i mean some more info than segmentation fault?

The code is actually quite long to paste it here so I giving links from Dropbox so you can look at it in-case you want to and then see what's the problem.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39063416/conway.tar.gz

its an implementation of conway's game of life program

Comment: You have a memory corruption, check the output of your program with `valgrind`.

Comment: Maybe it has `void main()` in it ? (in the part that you did not show)

Comment: @wildplasser nope "int main( int argc, char *argv[] )"

Comment: How should I know? Why don't you post it here (in reduced form). I am not willing to download and unpack your tarfile.

Comment: compile your program with debugging symbols (`-ggbd3` with gcc) and run it under a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strcpy( game.name , &result );// result is only char.
```

Comment: yes it gives the address of result which if which is equal to result[0] is result was a string. it kind of works is it this causing it to crash?

Comment: @shunya ; read reference of `strcpy`. direction to see by examining the operation of the `strcpy` is good. This is destroying the stack almost certainly.

Comment: @shunya Note that `strcpy`'s assume that is terminated by `'\0'`.

Comment: `strtok(&result, ".");` Have the same problem too.

Comment: thanks for the input i am fixing it now.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no way to be sure, even with you posting all your code.  The only way to really determine what is going on is to run your code with valgrind and look for memory corruption issues.

Here's a quick start guide.  http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html

Answer (score 0):

It's probably stack corruption. `main()` is not the first function executed in your application and it's not the last either. `main()` is just an user supplied function called from `crt0.c` (or whatever name has your toolchain supplied startup runtime module). If `main()` writes on stack area beyond its allocated stack frame, it will probably overwrite the return address, so when it finishes, won't return to its original caller, but to.... who knows.